# Ocultar <td> de tabela em algumas resoluções de celular

Tags: html, bootstrap, table, layout-responsivo

Tenho uma pagina em HTML em bootstrap ele já é responsivo. Mas preciso que quando acessarem o site em certa resolução definida por mim oculte apenas um  de uma tabela isso é possivel?

Comment: Você quer somente saber como faz ou aplicar em seu código? Caso seja a segunda opção, edite a pergunta com o mesmo.

Comment: Aplicar no código

Comment: Você pode usar o JS para identificar a resolução da tela window.screen ex.: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml

Answer (score 3):

Você possui os utilitários de responsabilidade que permitem fazer isso sem precisar de CSS externos ao Framework:

Para exibir:

```
.visible-xs-*
.visible-sm-*
.visible-md-*
.visible-lg-*
```

*(asterisco) - Pode ser: `'block'`, `'inline'` e `'inline-block'`.

Para ocultar:

```
.hidden-xs
.hidden-sm
.hidden-md
.hidden-lg
```

Basta adicionar ao elemento que deseja que seja disparado esse estilo.

OBS:

```
XS = Extra small (Menor que 768px)
SM = Small (Maior ou igual a 768px)
MD = Medium (Maior ou igual a 992px)
LG = Large (Maior ou igual a 1200px)
```

Exemplo de aplicaçao de uso:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="" >Exibe Todos</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs">Exibe SM ou maior</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Exibe MD ou maior</td>   
        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Exibe LG</td>    
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ai como eu faço? tipo <td class="hidden-xs"> isso? quero saber como ativar na coluna que quero que oculte

Comment: Isso mesmo, so adicionar o classname no 'td' ou 'tr' que quer ocultar, se quer ocultar em dispositivos pequenos usa '<td class='hidden-xs'></td>', funciona pra qualquer elemento, não só com tds, pode usar com 'div', 'span' e todos os outros.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso apenas com CSS.

Defina uma resolução máxima de largura e dentro os itens que deseja ocutar.

Por exemplo ocultando uma coluna com largura máxima de tela de 450px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
 td.classecolunaesconder{display:none; }
}
```